# Python: get unsorted list of singular values from numpy/scipy svd

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

I have a square matrix and want to use svd to reduce condition number of the matrix by elimination of some rows/columns.

I used numpy/scipy both give sorted list of singular values.

Using sorted list, I can easily reconstruct a smaller matrix by discarding some small singular values. But it is difficult to map to the original matrix, that what values have been eliminated and what values have been retained. I need that further.

Is there any way to identify later for the original matrix, what indices have been retained and what discarded.

Comment: You will need to add some clarification. The singular vectors are a linear combination of the original features. The singular values quantify the amount of the variance preserved in this new feature.

Comment: @FChm Condition number is the ratio of maximum/minimum singular values. So removing some set of small singular values can help in managing the condition number of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

To perform a singular value decomposition of a matrix you can look at the [.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) module in numpy.

A SVD of a matrix factorizes it into the product of three matrices:

**M** = **U S V***

**M** is your original matrix. **S** is a rectangular diagonal matrix with the ('sorted') singular values on the diagonals. **U** and **V** are known as the left- and right-singular vectors respectively.

Note: np.linalg.svd doesn't return **S** but **s** which is just a 1D array containing the singular values.

**Practical implementation**

Lets say you have an (m x q) feature space represented by the 2D array `X`, where `X` is a centered matrix. You can calculate its SVD:

```
U, s, Vt = np.linalg.svd(X)
```

where the `t` denotes the transpose of V and s is your 'unsorted list of singular values'.

You can then project your original feature space to `n` dimensions by using the singular vectors and discarding singular vectors which preserve the least variance:

```
X_projected = X.dot(Vt.T[:,:n])
```

where `X_projected` is now the representation of your feature space in the lower n-dimensional space.

Importantly, you can transform back from your reduced feature space to your original space:

```
X_recovered = X_projected.dot(Vt[:,:n])
```

Notably, this can be used to measure the information lost in your reduced feature set by comparing `X_recovered` to your original feature set (`X`) to measure things such as reconstruction error.